# Remove values from Select via jquery based value wildcard

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a script that I would like to loop through a SELECT named "Date" and remove OPTIONS from the SELECT if they are NOT %like% my search terms.

HTML -

```
<input type=text id="filteredlanguages" hidden value="Spanish, Latin">

<select name="Date" id="Date" class="form-control input-lg">
<option value="selection">Select Date</option>
<option value="2021-01-11T00:00:00.000Z">11 January - 12 March (English)</option>
<option value="2021-03-22T00:00:00.000Z">22 March - 21 May (Spanish)</option>
<option value="">I havent decided yet</option></select>
```

```
var filteredLanguages = $('#filteredlanguages').val().split(",");
$("#Date > option").each(function(i){
        if($.inArray($(this).val(), filteredLanguages) == -1) {
                //alert($(this).val());
                if ($(this).val() != "selection") {
                    $("#Date option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();
                }
        }
});`
```

So basically my Search Term is "Spanish" and "Latin" as per the element `#filteredlanguages`
I want the jquery code to Remove every OPTION from the `Date` Select Element if it doesnt contain the word "Spanish" or "Latin".

I hope someone can help.
thanks

Comment: Do you have a *single* search term? as in your examples "Spanish" and in your question "my search term" "value wildcard" - or do you have multiple search terms `["Spanish","Latin"]` as in your code `.split(",")`?  If multiple does it have to match all or any?

Comment: Multiple search terms yes.. so if Spanish, english then remove all options that dont contain any of these words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code:

- You should split `filteredlanguages` on a regex to allow for spaces between words
- You are comparing the `value` of the option (which is a date string) with the language; you should be comparing the text of the option instead.
- You should be checking whether any of the filteredLanguages values exist in the option text; you can do this with [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- You can remove an option simply with `$(this).remove()`

This code will do what you want:

```js
var filteredLanguages = $('#filteredlanguages').val().split(/\s*,\s/);
$('#Date > option').each(function(i) {
  let val = $(this).val();
  if (val == 'selection' || val == '') return;
  let text = $(this).text();
  if (!filteredLanguages.some(l => text.includes(l))) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="filteredlanguages" hidden value="Spanish, Latin">

<select name="Date" id="Date" class="form-control input-lg">
  <option value="selection">Select Date</option>
  <option value="2021-01-11T00:00:00.000Z">11 January - 12 March (English)</option>
  <option value="2021-03-22T00:00:00.000Z">22 March - 21 May (Spanish)</option>
  <option value="">I havent decided yet</option>
</select>
```